# Widget + ListView - how to handle app being stopped

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, remoteview, android-remoteview

I implemented a Homescreen Widget containing a ListView, just like the [CommonsWare sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget). In this sample project the `RemoteViewsFactory` holds a static final list of the entries to be displayed in the list. This items are always available of course.

In my case this data gets loaded from a webservice and stored in a static field in my `RemoteViewsFactory`. Now when the app is stopped, the items of course are no longer available. So the views still get displayed but as soon as the user scrolls through the list nothing is being displayed anymore.

How would you deal with this case?